# Dynamically display a control depending on bound property using WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I've got a property which is a database data type (`char`, `DateTime`, `int`, `float` etc...) and I want to change the control used to enter a value of the selected type. So for text values I want a `TextBox` and for date values I want a `DatePicker`.

One way I thought about doing it was to have one of each control on my form and set their `Visibility` using an appropriate `IValueConverter` implementation. I know this will work, but it would create a lot of code and doesn't feel very nice.

The other way I thought was to use a `ContentPresenter` and set its content with a `Style` and `DataTriggers` but I can't get it to work.

```
<Style x:Key="TypedValueHelper" TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataType}" Value="Char">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="???"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataType}" Value="Date">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="???"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataType}" Value="Integer">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="???"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If anyone can fill in my **"???"** or offer a better solution please do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could do a combination of style with setters and DataTemplates. You basically have the start for it in your code, although I don't think `ContentPresenter` is the right control to style, since it does not have a template.

Create a style like this:

```
<Style x:Key="TypedValueHelper" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataType}" Value="Char">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataType}" Value="Integer">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Slider Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Value="{Binding Path=.}"
                                         Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then use the style in the `ContentControl`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyValue}"
                        Style="{StaticResource TypedValueHelper}">
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can share my code as there are a lot of dependencies. In fact my actual problem is a little more complicated than I've let on. I'm pretty sure you're solution will work for me I've just got an issue where I'm trying to set the ContentControl's Content to {Binding} rather than {Binding MyValue} which means that WPF loads the View for my ViewModel in the content control, and recursively keeps going...

Comment: Ah I see. Did you try {Binding Path=.}?

Comment: Sorted! I had to set the DateType of the <DataTemplate> to the type of of the ViewModel. I guess this creates a locally scoped binding between the ViewModel type and the View I want to display. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 15):

While the `Style` solution might work, the proper way to implement the dynamic content behavior would be to use DataTemplates as Sdry suggested.  However, you would be using an enumeration to determine which DataTemplate to use, which essentially means you want to map a single type to multiple DataTemplates. This problem is solved by the `DataTemplateSelector` class, the following description is straight from MSDN:

> "Typically, you create a DataTemplateSelector when you have more than one DataTemplate for the same type of objects and you want to supply your own logic to choose a DataTemplate to apply based on the properties of each data object."

You dynamic content should be hosted by a `ContentControl` like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=ReferenceToYourViewModel}" ContentTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource MyTemplateSelector}"/>
```

The implementation of `MyTemplateSelector`:

```
public class MyTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement elem = container as FrameworkElement;
        if(elem == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (item == null || !(item is YourViewModel))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException();
        }
        if ((item as YourViewModel).DataType == DataType.Char)
        {
            return elem.FindResource("CharDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        if ((item as YourViewModel).DataType == DataType.Date)
        {
            return elem.FindResource("DateDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        if ((item as YourViewModel).DataType == DataType.Integer)
        {
            return elem.FindResource("IntegerDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        throw new ApplicationException();
    }
}
```

Then as you would expect, here are the DataTemplates to pick from:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CharDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type YourViewModel}">Put Your Xaml Here</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="DateDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type YourViewModel}">Put Your Xaml Here</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="IntegerDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type YourViewModel}">Put Your Xaml Here</DataTemplate>
```

With this, the appropriate `DataTemplate` will be chosen based on the `DataType` Property of your View Model. Which in my opinion is a lot cleaner than using `Visibility` or Styles.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into DataTemplates. For instance:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Input}">
    <local:InputControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:VideoData}">
    <local:VideoControl DataContext="{Binding}"></local:VideoControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work for me as I'm not using an actual 'Type' to make my choice of control, I'm using an enumeration value exposed as a property on my ViewModel.